# Как найти все файлы соответствующие следующему описанию?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

У меня на сервере есть папка, вот её путь:  /Images/Products/. 
В этой папке лежат фотографии. Имена этих фотографий я сгенерировал сам, вот таким способом: /{ProductID_}{DateTime.Now.ToString}.{Extension}
Как найти все файлы конкретного продукта, чтобы удалить?

Вот мой код, но он почему то не работает.

```
var images = string.Format("~/Images/Products/{0}_",ProductID);
                    foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles(MapPath(images),"*.*"))
                    {
                        File.Delete(path);
                    }
```

Comment: Получить список имен файлов в папке, отфильтровать и удалить нужные. В чем именно проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var imageDir = MapPath("~/Images/Products");
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(imageDir, ProductID + "_*.*"))
{
  File.Delete(file);
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо,я поняла в чём дело